# jQuery show 20 next element onClick event

Tags: jquery, loops

I am building a form that load 100 rows from my DB and it add a class name "noShow" (display:none) on the 80 lasts elements.

I have made a button where I want to show 20 more elements when I click on it.

So onload, I got 20 display:block and 80 display:none;

I am actually trying to loop the detection and remove the class but it does not seems to work.

```
$('#afficher_plus_sanair').bind('click', function()
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) 
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('table tbody tr.noShow').first().removeClass('noShow').show();
    }



});
```

As you can see, I have used the .first() and it was working correctly for "one by one" element.

```
$('#afficher_plus_sanair').bind('click', function()
{

        $(this).parent().parent().find('table tbody tr.noShow').first().removeClass('noShow').show();


});
```

**How could I acheive to get the 20 nexts and when I click again the script continues where it was?**

---

### HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
..
<tbody>
<tr >
<td>20</td>
</tr>

<tr style='display:none;' class='noShow'>                                                  
<td>21</td>   
</tr>
</tobdy>
</table>
```

Comment: what is `afficher_plus_sanair` and the html also

Comment: it should be something as simple as `$('#afficher_plus_sanair').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').('tr.noShow').slice(0, 20).removeClass('noShow').show();
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#afficher_plus_sanair').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('table tbody tr.noShow').nextAll(':lt(20)').removeClass('noShow').show();
});
```

`.nextAll()` will give you all following siblings of table row with `noShow` class.

and `:lt(20)` will filter out the 20 elements from it having index less than 20.

Comment: This method actually works quite good, but I can't show an other 20 elements. I think it is maybe because it target only the 0,20?

Answer (score 1):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/dys9W/2/)

Try this

You don't have to use classes, you can get hidden elements, which avoids adding and removing classes and you can get the exact element too.Below is the code

```
 $("#button").click(function () {
        $(".table-striped tr:hidden").slice($(".table-striped tr:hidden").first().index(),20).show();
    });
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try `slice()` on `nextAll()`:

for example if you need next 20 elements from current element you can try:

```
var nextTwenty = $(this).nextAll().slice(0,20);
```

try this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('table tbody tr.noShow').first().nextAll().slice(0,20);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. It seems like it only show the 20 first elements.. And when I bind a new click, it would normally slice with the 20 next because we check the first class "noShow" founded. 

I'll try to find a way to make it possible.

Comment: nextAll is from current element eg if you are 21 to 40 list then pass   $("40th-element").nextAll() then it will take next from 40

Comment: That the point where my knowledge in jQuery is limited. How can I detect that I'm now at the 40th element?